# How to rotate THREE.TubeGeometry segments?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created a flat THREE.TubeGeometry with radiusSegments = 2, which when added to the scene is perpendicular to the ground:

[image]

Is it possible to rotate each tube segment so that they would be parallel to the ground?

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/m4wpu8q5/4/)

```
var points = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   var randomY = i*5/2*10 + -50;
   var randomX = 15*Math.sin(5*i);
   points.push(new THREE.Vector3(randomX, randomY, 0));
}
var tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(new THREE.SplineCurve3(points), 64, 6, 2, false);
tubeMesh = createMesh(tubeGeometry);
scene.add(tubeMesh);
```

Comment: Am I blind or don't you really have a TubeGeometry on the picture?

Comment: @Zagoda TubeGeometry with radiusSegments = 2 looks like a ribbon.

Comment: From where do you get the vertices?

Comment: @juagicre I've added an example JSFiddle with 5 random points.

Comment: I see several things that I still want to have clear before giving an answer... what is for you a tube? the generated geometry looks flat, like a road. I understand you want a kind of road? You just want this road to be on the plane? I also see that the road geometry faces are not well created, as they do not display correctly.

Comment: @juagicre Yes, I want a kind of a road on the plane. Doesn't necessarily have to be a tube, it just looked like the easiest solution. Ignore the faces, it might as well be just a MeshBasicMaterial of some color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation for you is to use a custom flat geometry (not the TubeGeometry!) and calculate the vertices where you want them to be (not to rotate!).

Methodology to get your geometry is something like:

1. Create random points (here some math is needed in order to have them where you want them to be, but this is the funny part!)
2. Get spline points from each curve
3. Triangulate over them

If you decide to go forward with your code here the change to have it parallel to the plane. Add to generateTube function, after the tubeMesh creation:

```
tubeMesh.rotateY(Math.PI/2);
```